# I want to overlap two lines of text using line height - top line infront

Tags: css

I need to overlap two lines of text but want the second line underneath the top line. How is this possible using css?

http://jsfiddle.net/vkpv9ua0/

```css
   body {
 font-size:30px;
 font-family:"bebas-neue", Haettenschweiler, "Franklin Gothic Bold", "Arial Black", sans-serif;
 background:#50ACFF;
 font-weight:bold;
 
}

.red-text {
 color:#c14345;
 padding-left: 50px;
    text-indent:-50px;
 
}

p.logo::first-line { 
    z-index:99999;

  color:#FFFFFF;
 
}


p {
 z-index:-9999;
 

}

p.logo {
 line-height:20px;
}
```

```html
<p class="logo">
<span class="white-text"> CAT | DOG </span><br> <span class="red-text">FISHES</span>
</p>
```

Comment: I am not sure what are you trying to achieve here. you want the red text on top the white one in same position or you want it left aligned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a start for you.  This does what you want, you will just have to mess around with the positioning.

```
.red-text {
    color:#c14345;
    padding-left: 50px;
    text-indent:-50px;
    top:-30px;
    position:relative;
}

.white-text { 
    position:relative;
    z-index:99999;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJPDx.png)? If yes, you can just change the pixels to this  in @Dominofoe 's code:

```
 <p class="logo">
 <span class="white-text"> CAT | DOG </span>
 <br> <span class="red-text">FISHES</span>
 </p>


<head>
<style>
.red-text {
color:#c14345;
padding-left: 50px;
text-indent:-20px;
top:-11px;
position:relative;
}

.white-text { 
position:relative;
z-index:99999;

</style>
</head>
```

Comment: Pleasure @HywelIngham